# React App cannot call Spring Boot webservice within OpenShift

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, openshift

Given a React application deployed in OpenShift in its own pod and a Spring Boot webservice in another pod, but within the same namespace, the React application fails to call the webservice.

The Spring Boot webservice has a service:

```
    NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
    backend-api    ClusterIP   <Redacted>       <none>        8080/TCP,8443/TCP,8778/TCP   6m
```

React Developer Tools shows this issue:

`backend-api:8080/api/widgets:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

On the React pod, running `curl -v http://backend-api:8080/api/widgets` correctly responds with data and a 200 response code.

We have tried configuring the Spring Boot app to allow CORS:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
        }
    };
}
```

but this has not changed anything.

We want to keep the webservice in a separate pod and do not want to have to make it available outside of this namespace.

**Update**

XHR Fetch results per comment from @HMR

```
fetch("http://backend-api:8080/api/widgets", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  },
  "referrer": "<redacted>",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

Comment: In the browser devtool network tab (chrome) you can right click the xhr and choose copy -> copy fetch. If you can't figure out what is wrong with the fetch then maybe you can post it in your question.